# In android how to clear the animation of one button when another button is pressed?

Tags: android

I have a "Play again" button and a "home" button. The play again button has been animated at the end of the game. The code is as follows

```
private void playagain(){
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    animation.setDuration(500); // duration
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playagain);
    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn.bringToFront();
    btn.startAnimation(animation);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            view.clearAnimation();
            btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.home).performClick();
        }
    });
}
```

It animates the button and stops the animation and brings up the home screen, but if the home button is clicked, then also I want the play again button to become invisible and clear the animation.

v.clearAnimation(); in the onclick method of the homebutton doesn't clear up the animation. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept a click on the home button and act accordingly.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        // clear animation here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope it helps.